# See Google Analytics tracking stats from short cross domain redirect URL used in print media

Tags: redirects, analytics, tracking

I am using a different domain for some ads to track how many people access the main site through this domain.

How can I see this in Google Analytics?

I have DOMAIN A (on the ad) redirecting to DOMAIN B (main site).

Comment: Why use a domain rather than UTM parameters that work well in Google Analytics?   GA is notoriously bad at tracking redirects because no JS can run on the redirect.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Because on print advertising I am trying to use a very simple domain name so that people  are more likely to access it easily and remember it. Any creative ideas for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the redirect so that it adds UTM parameters.  Instead of:

```
http://domaina.example/ -> http://domainb.example/
```

Use the [Google Analytics Campaign URL Builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/) to build your final URL something like:

```
http://domaina.example/ -> http://domainb.example/?utm_source=the-global-times&utm_medium=print&utm_campaign=2019-push
```

That way your customers will be able to type in the simple short URL and Google Analytics will get the data it needs to track your campaign.

Comment: That's a fantastic and simple explanation. Thank you!